# Echo string containing functions and arguments

Tags: php, html

Im trying to use an echo statement in a php file that outputs HTML to a web page  (see below)

```
$name = 'bob';

echo '<button type="button" onclick="Function("'.$name.'")">name</button>';
```

where Function() is a JS function in the HTML page that accepts a single string argument.

The problem I am having is that the $name variable is not being "echoed" out with the rest of the statement and therefore the function isn't being correctly called.

I know the issue is because of the incorrect use of multiple " and '  but I cannot work out the fix for it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Typo `(?)` => `Fuction` - `Function` ;) (as per your original post).

Comment: you should really name your functions something other than Function

Comment: *"where Function() is a JS function in the HTML page that accepts a single string argument."* - Show your JS/full code.

Comment: Added some more of the code.

And I don't actually name real functions "Function()"  I only chose that name for posting the question

Comment: You're calling `AssignTest()` but it doesn't exist. Plus, you shouldn't be calling a function `Function()` - It could have adverse effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape your quotes:

```
echo '<button type="button" onclick="Function(\''.$name.'\')">name</button>';
```

Notice I change the inner quotes to single quotes so they do not conflict with the `onclick` attributes double quotes.

Comment: [`cough`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668964/echo-string-containing-functions-and-arguments#comment40113820_25668964)

Comment: I saw that but assumed that was a fictitious name as nobody would actually name a function `function()` would they?

Comment: Yeah, one never knows ;) watching your back.

Comment: I tried that but on the webpage it gives the error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\My Websites\test.php on line 69

Comment: That line doesn't have a syntax error. Show your actual code around that line so we can see what it really looks like.

Comment: My guess; it could have something to do with OP's [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25508222/)

Comment: Have updated with more info.

And I only called a function "Function()" for posting online.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code around that line that would cause an error. If you comment the line in question does it work?